# Is there a way to change from click to hover on my thumbnail gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a thumbnail gallery using *EasyZoom*.
But the event is onclick and i really would love to make it on hover

*HTML*

```
<div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay easyzoom--with-thumbnails">
                <a href="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/big/drewniane-ramki.png">
                    <img src="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/big/drewniane-albumy.png" alt="" width="640" height="360" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/big/drewniane-albumy.png" data-standard="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/cropped-1/drewniane-albumy.png">
                        <img src="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/cropped-1/drewniane-albumy.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/big/drewniane-ramki.png" data-standard="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/cropped-1/drewniane-ramki.png">
                        <img src="http://www.messa.dobre-strony.org/upload/cropped-1/drewniane-ramki.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="example-images/3_zoom_3.jpg" data-standard="example-images/3_standard_3.jpg">
                        <img src="example-images/3_thumbnail_3.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Full code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoaGbP)

I expect it to be hover not click

Comment: Replace `click` with `mouseover` event which trigger on mouse over.

Comment: "*Full code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoaGbP)*" please include your [mcve] code here in your question, including the JavaScript you're using in this case.

Comment: mouseover instead of click helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change line 350

```
    $('.thumbnails').on('mouseover', 'a', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
```

However, this changes the "target" img on 'mouseover'. The EasyZoom seems to be working by itself 'onmouseover'